# sinatra javascript call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

In rails, it is possible to set `:remote => true` to make a remote call to the web application. One can then respond with a `.js.erb` to changes elements. How would I create this in Sinatra? I want to do a remote delete on a resource and if successful, update Dom, else throw error.

Comment: you can add a delete route for the resource and answer with a status code. You can call this route with an ajax call from the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails, setting `:remote => true` using the `link_to` helper results in the following output:

```
<a href="#yoururl" data-remote="true">Linktext</a>
```

This link is observed in `rails.js` via something like:

```
$(document).on('click.remote', '[data-remote]', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: $(this).data('method') || 'GET',
    // and so on...
  });
});
```

What it therefore actually does is mark your `HTML` link with the `data-remote="true"` attribute, and then handles it via `js`. The `js.erb` template you can respond with is then evaled via the `DOM`. (Which I personally think is a bad idea).

In Sinatra, you can do pretty much the same: Mark your links with, for example, a `remote` class (which provides a faster lookup for js than the one rails uses via `[data-remote]`:

```
<a href="#yoururl" class="remote">Your Link Text</a>
```

Then bind the links having the remote class via jQuery: Observe the whole document for click events originating from elements with the remote class the way rails does it:

```
$(document).on('click.remote', '.remote', function() {
  // a similar ajax call to the one rails uses
});
```

Then, respond with `JSON` in `sinatra` and [`Sinatra::JSON`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html):

```
get '/yoururl' do
  json :foo => 'bar'
end
```

And do what you like with the data in the success handler of the ajax call. Or, you can also respond with a script written in erb (which is what rails does with `.js.erb`):

```
get '/yoururl' do
  erb :"answer.js"
end
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but looks about right. Thanks for digging into rails.js and finding the answer..I didn't know where to look. Would you be able to tell me what this particular line does? on('click.remote', '.remote' => click.remote? I know .remote targets the class remote

Comment: `$(document).on('click.remote', '.remote', function() {})` installs an observer looking for `click` events originating from elements having the class `remote` bubbling to the `document`. The `remote` in the event type string (`click.remote`) is a namespace helping you to be able to unbind just that handler using `off('click.remote')`. Without the namespace, you would only be able to unbind all the click events bound to document, which is not very flexible.